# Delete "*" index template

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I somehow accidentailly created a index template with "*" as the name:

```
 "*": {
"order": 0,
"index_patterns": [
  "*"
],
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "number_of_replicas": "0"
  }
},
```

I am now trying to delete it as it applies to all index patterns and I can't target it using the API. If I do:

```
GET /_template/*
```

it provides a list of all my templates.

I've tried:

```
GET /_template/"*"
```

which doesn't exist.

I've also tried using various escape characters but haven't been able to make it work yet.

How can I target this specific template using the API?

Thanks!
Gen.

Comment: Try \* or perhaps \\*     If not, you might try one of the UI tools.

Comment: I already tried * by itself - it targets ALL the templates whereas \* produces error: "reason": "request [/_template//*] contains unrecognized parameter: [name]"

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of these UI tools?

Comment: There used to be 'kopf', which looks like it was replaced by 'cerebro'  https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit counterintuitive, but GETing the * template doesn't work as expected, while DELETEing does. I tried the following:

```
PUT _template/*
{
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "0"
    }
  }
}

GET _template

DELETE _template/*

GET _template
```

The first GET includes the * template, the second one doesn't any more.

Comment: Thanks for the input but, if I do DELETE _template/* the * template will get deleted but it's not the ONLY template to get deleted. Try the above but add some more test templates with various names and then run DELETE _template/*. This will delete ALL the previous templates you created. I need to delete only the * template.

Comment: Indeed, I only tested it with the built in indices (`logstash-index-template`,...) and only those survive. This is unfortunately surprisingly tricky. There is an existing issue on the repo and your only option seems to be to get all index templates, delete everything, and recreate with the right names: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25645#issuecomment-320256626

Comment: Thanks - it's a weird issue that PUT doesn't behave the same way as GET/DELETE. It seems like a lot of effort to delete all the templates (especially if you have many) and then re-create without the *. Unless there is a simple way that I'm not aware of? As a workaround in the meantime, I edited the * template using PUT and set a index pattern that I would not use in logstash as well as setting the order to the maximum value.

Comment: Looking at that issue I'm afraid there is no alternative at the moment.